# Change area of usability in LCD touch Screen

Tags: android, layout, screen

Would it be possible to edit android source code lets say for the Galaxy S to only use a certain portion of the lcd screen. Say much like changing the resolution but creating it so only say 1 inch down would be usable. The rest inoperative.

Just curious if this is a hardware or software thing.

And does it have anything to do with this? 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html

But i am talking about the device as a whole. Natively say changing a rom to only display from this section and nothing below. As if the screen was that big.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to experiment just for fun but i want to know how to do this.

Comment: Yeah i wanna find out where exactly to do that haha. Do you think its inside build.prop and im guessing just change resolution right?

Comment: The only issue is how to type? What about replacing the screen?

Comment: This is definitely possible because i can run an emulator with these dimensions

Comment: for an application or for the phone?